# Angular2: Subscribed Method is not fired when called from another component

Tags: angular, components, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I'm trying to update the data from one component, and receive it into another component sing `Subject` and `Observables`.

### **Problem**

I am able to store data in `datShareService`, but my `getData` never gets called once data is updated.

I have following code structure

**fileComponent.ts** tries to store some data in dataShareService

```
{
...
//call dataShareService and update data
this.dataShareService.updateData(this.things);
...
}
```

**dataShareService.ts** would get the data and return it when asked

```
{
...
private outputs = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }


  getData(): Observable<any>{
    console.log('getData', this.outputs.asObservable());
    return this.outputs.asObservable();
  }

  updateData(outputs:any): void{
    this.outputs.next(outputs);
    console.log('datashare', this.outputs);
  }
...
}
```

**resultsComponents.ts** which has subscribed to `getData` method

```
{
...
public results : any;
  private sub : Subscription;

  constructor(private dataShareService: DatashareService) {
    console.log(this.dataShareService);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.dataShareService.getData().subscribe(output => {
      this.results = output;
    });
    console.log('visual result arrived', this.results);
  }
...
}
```

I'm almost certain that the problem is with the sequence these methods are called, yet not sure where exactly.

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting no value then you have to change your dataShareService.ts as follow

```
 {
   ...
   private outputs = new Subject<any>();

   constructor() { }


   getData(): Observable<any>{
    console.log('getData', this.outputs.asObservable());
    return this.outputs.asObservable();
   }

    updateData(outputs:any): void{
    this.outputs.next({text:outputs});
    console.log('datashare', this.outputs);
   }
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put `console.log('visual result arrived', this.results);` outside your subscribe method.

Put your `console.log('visual result arrived', this.results);` inside subscribe method then whenever data is updated it will get printed to console.

Below is

[working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjdgwv?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Use ReplaySubject instead of Subject, that way it'll emit previous values aswell